# How can I bring view to top in LinearLayout without change index of the view?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

For example, here are 6 child views in LinearLayout.

- LinearLayout

  - View0
  - View1
  - View2
  - View3
  - View4
  - View5

In some case, I want to make View0 on the top of other views, that's to say, View0 cannot be overlapped by other views.

There are methods `bringToFront` and `bringChildToFront`, they will change the index of View0 to:

- LinearLayout

  - View1
  - View2
  - View3
  - View4
  - View5
  - View0

I have tried `ViewCompat.setTranslationZ` method, however, it does not work.

How can I make View0 on top of other views without change View0's index?

Comment: If you look at the source, you'll see that ViewCompat method doesn't actually do anything on older SDK levels.

Comment: @AutonomousApps yeah, I should notice that.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to subclass `LinearLayout`, use `setChildDrawingOrderEnabled(true)`, and override `getChildDrawingOrder()` to return the index of the item last.

So in your example, you would return the following in `getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i)`:

```
return (childCount + (i-1)) % childCount;
```

Comment: `use setChildDrawingOrderEnabled(true)` I think this method should be `setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled`, however, It still does not work...

Comment: I try with `return childCount - i - 1;`, I works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting layout gravity to `Gravity.TOP` for the View0.